# How to restrict jasper report not to start on a new page for every group?

Tags: jasper-reports, grouping

I am new to Jasper Reports. In my project, the version being used is Jasper Reports 3.1.2. 
Problem is: I have a main report which displays the summary and 2 other subreports. The data is grouped on the basis of 2 fields and data is coming (already grouped) from the backend. In my jasper report, I have the following group and the following properties set:

```
<group name="groupName" isStartNewPage="true" isResetPageNumber="true" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true" >
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
        <band height="0"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
        </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
        <band height="0"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
        </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
```

Whenever a new group is seen, it prints the data on a new page.
I want the data not to get printed on a new page when there is enough space on the current page to accommodate other groups data.

I have already tried removing "isStartNewPage" property. Also, tried putting "keepTogether" property, but since it is an old version of Jasper report, this property is not supported.
I have tried changing the height values also, but no luck there.

I want to keep the data to one page when there is enough space to display records on a single page.

Output:
The first page displays the summary data and 2 groups by which the data has been grouped.
The second page shows the data of the first group which is a subreport of the first group.
Similarly, there is a third page which will have the data related to the 2nd group in the summary.

Jasper Report Page 1

[image]

Jasper Report Page 2

[image]

Comment: please share the report output

Comment: @Rathnayake I have edited my post and added 2 images which might help you understand the output of my Jasper Report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this group prints the data on new page by `isStartNewPage="true"` property. remove this property line for prints data on current page when there is enough space on the current page.

try with this,

```
<group name="groupName" isResetPageNumber="true" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true" >
    .......
</group>
```

Comment: I have already tried removing it. It is not working in my case.

Comment: What is the IDE? jasper studio, ireport designer or eclipse

Comment: I am using iReport 2.0.5.

Comment: @SurbhiDhawan deselect the checkbox "Start on a New Page" property or open the jrxml file using text editor and remove the `isStartNewPage="true"`. these both solutions work for me

Comment: Yes. It worked. 
The issue with my reports was the .jasper file was not updating whenever I was making the changes (folder location was wrong). I changed the folder in which .jasper file was stored. Now it works!!
Thanks a lot for your help @Rathnayake